# Simple definite integral

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals

I do not figure out how to solve

$$
L= \frac{1}{2}\int_1^4 \sqrt{(16t^2+t+4)}\;dt
$$

The key is probably in simplifying the polynomial equation, but I don't find a way that is really simplifying the integral. Can someone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Complete the square and use a trigonometric substitution.

Comment: It's not that easy. One shall know also the method of Secant substitution.

Comment: @Dr.MV  The completion of the square was the first step to the resolution, but I did not go through the trigonometric substitution. I used a table of integrals that I could use.

Comment: @KimPeekII Sure, it was more difficult that I thought, not knowing at first the table that was accessible.

Comment: That's fine.  Pleased to hear you have it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $$\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{4}\sqrt{16t^2+t+4}\ dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{4}4\sqrt{t^2+\frac{t}{16}+\frac{1}{4}}\ dt$$
$$=2\int_{1}^{4}\sqrt{\left(t+\frac{1}{32}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt {255}}{32}\right)^2}\ dt$$
using substitution, $t+\frac{1}{32}=t$, one should get 
$$=2\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(t+\frac{1}{32}\right)\sqrt{\left(t+\frac{1}{32}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt {255}}{32}\right)^2}+\frac{255}{32^2}\ln\left|\left(t+\frac{1}{32}\right)+\sqrt{\left(t+\frac{1}{32}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt {255}}{32}\right)^2}\right|\right]_1^4$$
I hope you can solve further

Comment: Yes thank you, I found the formula in a book where there were tables of integrals and a section for those containing $\sqrt{a^2+u^2}, a >0$ For the one who is interested :
$$
\int\sqrt{a^2+u^2} du = \frac{u}{2}\sqrt{a^2+u^2}+\frac{a^2}{2}ln(u+\sqrt{a^2+u^2}) + C
$$

Answer (score 1):

Not that easy. I will ignore the 1/2 factor and the extrema, by now.

$$16t^2 + t + 4 = \left(4t + \frac{1}{8}\right)^2 + \frac{255}{64}$$

Substitute then $z = 4t + \frac{1}{8}$ and $dz = 4 dt$ you have now:

$$\frac{1}{4}\int\sqrt{z^2 + \frac{255}{64}} dz$$

Now use the substitution $z = \frac{1}{8}\sqrt{255}\tan(s)$ and $dz = \frac{1}{8}\sqrt{255}\sec^2(s) dx$ this will lead to (make the math):

$$\frac{\sqrt{255}}{{32}}\int \frac{1}{8}\sqrt{255}\sec^3(s) ds = \frac{255}{256}\int \sec^3(s) dx$$

Now use the secant reduction formula:

$$\int \sec^m(x) dx = \frac{\sin(x)\sec^{m-1}(x)}{m-1} + \frac{m-2}{m-1}\int \sec^{m-2}(x) dx$$

and in your case $m = 3$. Remember that the integral of $\sec(x)$ is $\log(\tan(x) + \sec(x))$ and then you get:

$$\frac{255}{512}\tan(s)\sec(s) + \frac{255}{512}\log(\tan(s) + \sec(s))$$

Substitute back now. You had:

$$s = \arctan\left(\frac{8u}{255}\right)$$

and

$$u = \frac{1}{8} + 4y$$

obtaining:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{64}\sqrt{16t^2 + 4t + 4}(32t + 1) + \frac{255}{512}\log\left(\frac{8\sqrt{16t^2 + t + 4} + 32t + 1}{\sqrt{255}}\right)\right]_1^{4} = \text{do the math to obtain a number}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is giving me the right result, but this trigonometric substitution was above the level of difficulty of my course. I found the formula to solve the integral in reference tables. The form of the equation you obtained is not identical to the reference formula, but they are similar in the way they use the expression with logarithms, but with different bases.